# Report currently on datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, crystal-reports

Is it possible to only show in crystal report what is currently on the datagridview? Because what I want to do is when I search something from my datagridview, that is what I want to show up on my crystal report. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just give the correct source to Crystal:

```
Try
    Dim SQLstr As String = ""
    Dim crReportDocument As New ItemsRP
    Dim SqlDatpr As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    InvDataset.Clear()
    Flt = ("SELECT * FROM TBLXMLITEMS where Name Like  N'" &
          Trim$(txtsearch.Text) & "%' ORDER BY ID")

    InvDataset = GeneralDataManager.InquireData(InvDataset, Flt, "TBLXMLITEMS")
    SqlDatpr = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(Flt, SQLstr)
    crReportDocument.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(InvDataset)

    Dim rpt As New ItemsRP
    rpt.SetDataSource(InvDataset)

    Dim frm As New ShowPrintt 
    frm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    frm.Show()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```